# Returned Eigen Matrix from templated function changes value

Tags: c++, lambda, eigen, auto

I came around some weird behavior concerning the eigen library and templated functions.

Maybe someone can explain to me, why the first version is not working, while the other 3 do. My guess would be the first case freeing up some local variable, but hopefully someone can enlighten me. Thanks in advance.

Here is the code:

Compiler-Explorer: https://compiler-explorer.com/z/r45xzE417

```
#include <concepts>
#include <iostream>

#include <Eigen/Core>

auto RungeKutta1_auto(const auto& f, const std::floating_point auto& h, const auto& y_n)
{
    auto ret = y_n + h * f(y_n);
    std::cout << ret.transpose() << std::endl;
    return ret;
}

template<typename _Scalar, int _Rows, int _Cols>
auto RungeKutta1_template(const auto& f, const std::floating_point auto& h, const Eigen::Matrix<_Scalar, _Rows, _Cols>& y_n)
{
    Eigen::Matrix<_Scalar, _Rows, _Cols> ret = y_n + h * f(y_n);
    std::cout << ret.transpose() << std::endl;
    return ret;
}

int main()
{
    auto f = [](const Eigen::Matrix<double, 10, 1>& y) {
        Eigen::Matrix<double, 10, 1> y_dot = 2 * y;
        return y_dot;
    };

    auto g = [](const Eigen::Matrix<double, 10, 1>& y) {
        return 2 * y;
    };

    std::cout << "RungeKutta1_auto(f, 0.05, y):" << std::endl;
    Eigen::Matrix<double, 10, 1> y;
    y << 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9;
    y = RungeKutta1_auto(f, 0.05, y);
    std::cout << y.transpose() << std::endl;
    // Output
    //   0 1.1 2.2 3.3 4.4 5.5 6.6 7.7 8.8 9.9
    // 3.47627e-311            1            2            3            4            5          6.6            7            8            9

    std::cout << "RungeKutta1_template(f, 0.05, y):" << std::endl;
    y << 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9;
    y = RungeKutta1_template(f, 0.05, y);
    std::cout << y.transpose() << std::endl;
    // Output
    //   0 1.1 2.2 3.3 4.4 5.5 6.6 7.7 8.8 9.9
    //   0 1.1 2.2 3.3 4.4 5.5 6.6 7.7 8.8 9.9

    std::cout << "RungeKutta1_auto(g, 0.05, y):" << std::endl;
    y << 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9;
    y = RungeKutta1_auto(g, 0.05, y);
    std::cout << y.transpose() << std::endl;
    // Output
    //   0 1.1 2.2 3.3 4.4 5.5 6.6 7.7 8.8 9.9
    //   0 1.1 2.2 3.3 4.4 5.5 6.6 7.7 8.8 9.9

    std::cout << "RungeKutta1_template(g, 0.05, y):" << std::endl;
    y << 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9;
    y = RungeKutta1_template(g, 0.05, y);
    std::cout << y.transpose() << std::endl;
    // Output
    //   0 1.1 2.2 3.3 4.4 5.5 6.6 7.7 8.8 9.9
    //   0 1.1 2.2 3.3 4.4 5.5 6.6 7.7 8.8 9.9
}
```

Comment: Be careful when using `auto` with Eigen expressions: https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/TopicPitfalls.html#title3

Comment: thanks, that link was quite helpful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the first version,

```
auto ret = y_n + h * f(y_n);
```

due to Eigen's expression templates this gives you an intermediate expression type, as opposed to a `Matrix` type. You would need to explicitly invoke `eval()` on it to force the lazy eval to occur (and in such converting the expression to a resulting `Matrix` type object); e.g.:

```
auto ret = (y_n + h * f(y_n)).eval();
```

In the other versions you are explicitly typing out the type of `ret` to be a `Matrix` type, meaning you will not end up storing intermediate expression template types.

Comment: Thanks, I guess these expression templates are the reason while it fails.

The only thing still confusing me is, why the version with lambda `f` and function `RungeKutta1_auto` failes, while the lambda `g` and function `RungeKutta1_auto` does not.

I would have expected that the `g` lambda produces even more expression templates and therefore should fail even more. But I guess this goes too deep into the Eigen library and how they handle their types.

Anyway, thank you for your answer. This solves it for my part